# Fill missing values based on same ID

Tags: r, missing-data

In my data, I have an ID called `s_id_K` indicating the school of participants and a variable `schsizeK` indicating the school size. This means `schsizeK` should have the same value for participants with the same `s_id_K`. I have the case that within the same school the school size is missing for some participants. Now I want to fill in these missing values with the values of the other participants of the same school. In my dataframe there are many other variables that I do not want to manipulate. How can a syntax in R look like?

I tried this code but it did not work, meaning the NAs are still there and noting was changed:

```
test %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(s_id_K) %>% 
  fill(schsizeK, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

test <- structure(list(s_id_K = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("1001", 
"1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008", "1009", 
"1011", "1012", "1013", "1014", "1015", "1016", "1017", "1018", 
"1019", "1020", "1021", "1022", "1023", "1024", "1025", "1026", 
"1027", "1028", "1029", "1030", "1031", "1032", "1033", "1034", 
"1035", "1036", "1037", "1038", "1039", "1040", "1041", "1042", 
"1043", "1044", "1045", "1046", "1047", "1048", "1049", "1050", 
"1051", "1052", "1053", "1054", "1055", "1056", "1057", "1058", 
"1060", "1061", "1062", "1063", "1064", "1065", "1066", "1067", 
"1068", "1069", "1070", "1071", "1072", "1073", "1074", "1075", 
"1077", "1078", "1079", "1080", "1081", "1082", "1083", "1084", 
"1085", "1086", "1087", "1088", "1089", "1090", "1091", "1092", 
"1093", "1094", "1095", "1096", "1097", "1098", "1099", "1100", 
"1101", "1102", "1103", "1104", "1105", "1106", "1107", "1108", 
"1109", "1110", "1111", "1112", "1113", "1115", "1116", "1117", 
"1118", "1119", "1120", "1121", "1122", "1123", "1124", "1125", 
"1126", "1127", "1128", "1129", "1130", "1131", "1132", "1133", 
"1134", "1135", "1136", "1137", "1138", "1140", "1141", "1142", 
"1143", "1144", "1146", "1147", "1148", "1149", "1150", "1151", 
"1152", "1153", "1154", "1155", "1157", "1158", "1159", "1160", 
"1161", "1162", "1163", "1164", "1165", "1166", "1167", "1168", 
"1169", "1170", "1171", "1172", "1173", "1174", "1175", "1176", 
"1177", "1178", "1179", "1180", "1181", "1182", "1183", "1184", 
"1185", "1186", "1187", "1188", "1189", "1190", "1191", "1192", 
"1193", "1194", "1195", "1196", "1197", "1198", "1199", "1200", 
"1201", "1202", "1203", "1204", "1205", "1206", "1207", "1208", 
"1209", "1210", "1211", "1212", "1213", "1214", "1215", "1216", 
"1217", "1218", "1219", "1220", "1221", "1222", "1223", "1224", 
"1225", "1226", "1227", "1228", "1229", "1230", "1231", "1232", 
"1233", "1234", "1235", "1236", "1237", "1238", "1239", "1240", 
"1241", "1242", "1243", "1244", "1245", "1246", "1247", "1248", 
"1249", "1250", "1251", "1252", "1253", "1254", "1255", "1256", 
"1257", "1258", "1259", "1260", "1261", "1262", "1263", "1264", 
"1265", "1266", "1267", "1268", "1269", "1270", "1271", "1272", 
"1273", "1274", "1275", "1276", "1277", "1278", "1280", "1281", 
"1282", "1283", "1284", "1285", "1286", "1287", "1288", "1289", 
"1290", "1291", "1292", "1293", "1294", "1295", "1296", "1297", 
"1298", "1299", "1300", "1301", "1302", "1303", "1304", "1305", 
"1306", "1307", "1308", "1309", "1310", "1311", "1312", "1313", 
"1314", "1315", "1316", "1317", "1318", "1319", "1320", "1321", 
"1322", "1323", "1324", "1325", "1326", "1327", "1328", "1329", 
"1330", "1331", "1332", "1333", "1334", "1335", "1336", "1337", 
"1338", "1339", "1340", "1341", "1342", "1343", "1344", "1345", 
"1346", "1347", "1348", "1349", "1350", "1351", "1352", "1353", 
"1354", "1355", "1356", "1357", "1358", "1359", "1360", "1361", 
"1363", "1364", "1365", "1366", "1367", "1368", "1369", "1370", 
"1371", "1372", "1373", "1374", "1375", "1376", "1377", "1378", 
"1379", "1380", "1381", "1382", "1383", "1384", "1385", "1386", 
"1387", "1388", "1389", "1390", "1391", "1392", "1393", "1394", 
"1395", "1396", "1397", "1398", "1399", "1400", "1401", "1402", 
"1403", "1404", "1405", "1406", "1407", "1408", "1409", "1410", 
"1411", "1412", "1413", "1414", "1415", "1416", "1417", "1418", 
"1419", "1420", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1425", "1426", 
"1427", "1428", "1429", "1430", "1431", "1432", "1433", "1434", 
"1435", "1436", "1437", "1438", "1439", "1440", "1441", "1442", 
"1443", "1444", "1445", "1446", "1447", "1448", "1449", "1450", 
"1451", "1452", "1453", "1454", "1455", "1457", "1458", "1459", 
"1460", "1461", "1462", "1463", "1464", "1465", "1466", "1467", 
"1468", "1469", "1470", "1471", "1472", "1473", "1474", "1475", 
"1476", "1477", "1478", "1480", "1481", "1482", "1483", "1484", 
"1485", "1486", "1487", "1488", "1489", "1490", "1491", "1492", 
"1493", "1494", "1495", "1496", "1497", "1498", "1499", "1500", 
"1501", "1502", "1503", "1504", "1505", "1506", "1507", "1508", 
"1509", "1510", "1511", "1512", "1513", "1514", "1515", "1516", 
"1517", "1518", "1519", "1520", "1521", "1522", "1523", "1524", 
"1525", "1526", "1527", "1528", "1529", "1530", "1531", "1532", 
"1533", "1535", "1536", "1537", "1538", "1539", "1540", "1541", 
"1542", "1543", "1544", "1545", "1546", "1547", "1548", "1549", 
"1550", "1551", "1552", "1553", "1554", "1555", "1556", "1557", 
"1558", "1559", "1560", "1561", "1562", "1563", "1564", "1565", 
"1566", "1567", "1568", "1569", "1570", "1571", "1572", "1573", 
"1574", "1575", "1576", "1577", "1578", "1579", "1580", "1581", 
"1582", "1583", "1584", "1586", "1587", "1588", "1589", "1590", 
"1591", "1592", "1593", "1594", "1595", "1596", "1597", "1598", 
"1599", "1600", "1601", "1602", "1603", "1605", "1606", "1607", 
"1608", "1609", "1610", "1611", "1612", "1613", "1614", "1615", 
"1616", "1617", "1618", "1619", "1620", "1621", "1622", "1623", 
"1624", "1625", "1626", "1627", "1628", "1629", "1630", "1631", 
"1632", "1633", "1635", "1636", "1637", "1638", "1639", "1640", 
"1641", "1642", "1643", "1644", "1645", "1646", "1647", "1648", 
"1651", "1652", "1653", "1654", "1655", "1656", "1658", "1659", 
"1660", "1661", "1662", "1663", "1664", "1665", "1666", "1667", 
"1668", "1669", "1670", "1671", "1672", "1673", "1674", "1675", 
"1676", "1677", "1678", "1679", "1680", "1681", "1682", "1683", 
"1684", "1685", "1686", "1687", "1688", "1689", "1690", "1691", 
"1692", "1693", "1694", "1695", "1696", "1697", "1698", "1699", 
"1700", "1701", "1702", "1703", "1704", "1705", "1706", "1707", 
"1708", "1709", "1710", "1711", "1712", "1713", "1714", "1715", 
"1716", "1717", "1718", "1719", "1720", "1721", "1722", "1723", 
"1724", "1725", "1726", "1727", "1728", "1729", "1730", "1731", 
"1732", "1733", "1734", "1735", "1736", "1737", "1738", "1739", 
"1740", "1741", "1742", "1743", "1744", "1745", "1746", "1747", 
"1748", "1749", "1750", "1751", "1752", "1753", "1754", "1755", 
"1756", "1757", "1758", "1759", "1760", "1761", "1762", "1763", 
"1764", "1765", "1766", "1767", "1768", "1769", "1770", "1771", 
"1772", "1773", "1774", "1775", "1776", "1777", "1778", "1779", 
"1780", "1781", "1782", "1783", "1784", "1785", "1786", "1787", 
"1788", "1789", "1790", "1791", "1792", "1793", "1794", "1795", 
"1796", "1797", "1798", "1799", "1801", "1802", "1803", "1804", 
"1805", "1806", "1807", "1808", "1809", "1810", "1811", "1812", 
"1813", "1814", "1815", "1816", "1817", "1818", "1819", "1820", 
"1821", "1822", "1823", "1824", "1825", "1826", "1827", "1828", 
"1829", "1830", "1831", "1832", "1833", "1834", "1835", "1836", 
"1837", "1838", "1839", "1840", "1841", "1842", "1843", "1844", 
"1845", "1846", "1847", "1848", "1849", "1850", "1851", "1852", 
"1853", "1854", "1855", "1856", "1857", "1858", "1859", "1860", 
"1861", "1862", "1863", "1864", "1865", "1866", "1867", "1868", 
"1869", "1870", "1871", "1872", "1873", "1874", "1875", "1876", 
"1877", "1878", "1879", "1880", "1881", "1882", "1883", "1884", 
"1885", "1886", "1887", "1888", "1889", "1890", "1891", "1892", 
"1893", "1894", "1895", "1896", "1898", "1899", "1900", "1901", 
"1902", "1903", "1904", "1905", "1906", "1907", "1908", "1909", 
"1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", "1914", "1915", "1916", "1918", 
"1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", "1923", "1924", "1925", "1926", 
"1927", "1928", "1929", "1930", "1931", "1932", "1933", "1934", 
"1935", "1936", "1937", "1938", "1939", "1940", "1941", "1942", 
"1943", "1944", "1945", "1946", "1947", "1948", "1949", "1950", 
"1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1956", "1957", "1958", 
"1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", 
"1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", 
"1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", 
"1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", 
"1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", 
"1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", 
"2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", 
"2023", "2024", "2025", "2026", "2027", "2028", "2029", "2030", 
"2031", "2032", "2033", "2034", "2035", "2036", "2037", "2038", 
"2039", "2040", "2041", "2042", "2043", "2045", "2046", "2047", 
"2048", "2049", "2050", "2051", "2052", "2053", "2054", "2055", 
"2056", "2057", "2058", "2059", "2060", "2061", "2062", "2063", 
"2064", "2066", "2067", "2068", "2069", "2070", "2071", "2072", 
"2073", "2074", "2075", "2076", "2077", "2078", "2079", "2080", 
"2081", "2082", "2083", "2084", "2085", "2086", "2087", "2088", 
"2089", "2090", "2091", "2092", "2093", "2094", "2095", "2096", 
"2097", "2098", "2099", "2100", "2101", "2102", "2103", "2104", 
"2105", "2106", "2107", "2108", "2109", "2110", "2111", "2112", 
"2113", "2114", "2115", "2116", "2117", "2118", "2119", "2120", 
"2121", "2122", "2123", "2124", "2125", "2126", "2127", "2128", 
"2129", "2130", "2131", "2132", "2133", "2134", "2135", "2136", 
"2137", "2138", "2139", "2140", "2141", "2142", "2143", "2144", 
"2145", "2146", "2147", "2148", "2149", "2150", "2151", "2152", 
"2153", "2154", "2155", "2156", "2157", "2158", "2159", "2160", 
"2161", "2162", "2163", "2164", "2165", "2166", "2167", "2168", 
"2169", "2170", "2171", "2172", "2173", "2174", "2175", "2176", 
"2177", "2178", "2179", "2180", "2181", "2182", "2183", "2184", 
"2185", "2186", "2187", "2188", "2189", "2190", "2191", "2192", 
"2193", "2194", "2195", "2196", "2197", "2198", "2199", "2200", 
"2201", "2202", "2203", "2204", "2205", "2206", "2207", "2208", 
"2209", "2210", "2211", "2212", "2213", "2214", "2215", "2216", 
"2217", "2218", "2219", "2220", "2221", "2222", "2223", "2224", 
"2225", "2226", "2227", "2228", "2229", "2230", "2231", "2232", 
"2233", "2234", "2235", "2236", "2237", "2238", "2239", "2240", 
"2241", "2242", "2243", "2244", "2245", "2246", "2247", "2248", 
"2249", "2250", "2251", "2252", "2253", "2254", "2255", "2256", 
"2257", "2258", "2259", "2260", "2261", "2262", "2263", "2264", 
"2265", "2266", "2267", "2268", "2269", "2270", "2271", "2272", 
"2273", "2274", "2275", "2276", "2277", "2278", "2279", "2280", 
"2281", "2282", "2283", "2284", "2285", "2286", "2287", "2288", 
"2289", "2290", "2291", "2292", "2293", "2294", "2295", "2296", 
"2297", "2298", "2299", "2300", "2301", "2302", "2303", "2304", 
"2305", "2306", "2307", "2308", "2310", "2311", "2312", "2313", 
"2314", "2315", "2316", "2317", "2318", "2319", "2320", "2321", 
"2322", "2323", "2324", "2325", "2326", "2327", "2328", "2329", 
"2330", "2331"), class = "factor"), schsizeK = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(412L, 
621L, 1062L, 1334L, 1485L, 1694L, 1932L, 2472L, 3241L, 3310L, 
3369L, 4098L, 4661L, 4712L, 4875L, 5560L, 5636L, 6860L, 8200L, 
8563L, 9766L, 9773L, 10152L, 10474L, 10973L, 12018L, 12836L, 
12848L, 13355L, 14599L, 15064L, 16146L, 16292L, 16733L, 17142L, 
17345L, 17503L, 18120L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "did not work" means? Did it throw an error, give the wrong output, etc? You may need to add `.direction = "downup"` to your `fill()` statement. Also, you may get better, faster help if you edit your question to allow us to reproduce the issue (ie, providing the output of `dput(df)`). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I edited my question and created a smaller data set to provide dput(df).

Comment: You appear not to have assigned the result of your edit to an object.  Does `test <- test %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(s_id_K) %>% 
  fill(schsizeK, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()` give you what you want?  The additional information has lead me to vote to reopen.

Comment: @Limey if the issue was just that they meant to assign the result back to a variable but didn't, that doesn't warrant reopening. It's unclear if that was all it took to resolve the problem

Comment: @camille  originally, OP did not provide their code.  When they did, they satisfied our original criticism.  Hence my reopen vote.  I then asked if the problem was simply that they hadn't saved their changes - a question I couldn't ask before because the information was not available.  OP subsequently confirmed that was the case.  So now I think the question should be closed as a typo.  My opinion changes as the facts change.

Comment: @Limey got it, thanks. I guess there's no need to reopen just to close for a different reason, so I'm voting to keep it closed